# Application Renders different accessed via pow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rack, rack-pow

When viewing my app being served via [**Pow**](http://pow.cx/) (i.e. at `http://my_app.dev/`) it renders as follows:

[image]

When viewing my app via **webrick** or **thin** (i.e. `rails server webrick` or `rails server thin` at `http://localhost:3000`) it renders as follows:

[image]

The app was generated via [**rails_apps_compser**](http://railsapps.github.com/tutorial-rails-apps-composer.html) selecting the `twitter bootstrap (sass)` option.

What is causing the difference in the rendering of the application?  I understand **Pow** is a rack web server but what is actually responding to requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a different zoom setting in your browser for "localhost". Try resetting the zoom level.

(the following is taken from http://www.nikcub.com/posts/two-google-chrome-privacy-issues)

The zoom data is associated per domain, and is stored in the user Preferences file, which is part of the user profile - `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default` in OS X and `\Documents and Settings\%USER\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` on Windows (or AppData in Win8). The Preferences file is a plain text file that stores user preferences in JSON format.

The per host zoom settings are stored in this file and not deleted when the user deletes browser history, leaving a trail of visited domain names where the user has adjusted zoom settings.

An example of what it looks like:

```
"per_host_zoom_levels": {
     "": -1.0,
     "1.bp.blogspot.com": -0.5778829455375671,
     "2.bp.blogspot.com": 3.0,
     "3.bp.blogspot.com": 3.0,
     "4.bp.blogspot.com": -2.22938871383667,
     "account.onetruefan.com": -1,
     "acko.net": -1.0,
     "allthingsd.com": -1.0,
     "antirez.com": -1,
     "api.jquery.com": -0.5778829455375671,
     "apple.stackexchange.com": -1.0,
     "archive.guardian.co.uk": -1.0,
     "arstechnica.com": -0.5778829455375671
 }
```

Any other user or process with access to the user profile can access this information.

Comment: Accessing the application at `0.0.0.0:3000` renders it properly, thanks this is very good to know!

Answer (score 0):

View source or use a browser console, and see if the *CSS* is getting loaded. It looks like a *CSS* difference. It's possible that with *webrick* or *thin*, the *assets* aren't being put wherever the `stylesheet_include_tag` is expecting it. In other word, look up *rails asset pipeline*...